# Generating unique access code for two users to access same unique page in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm looking to create a site similar to http://owdraft.com where two links are generated which can then be used by users to access a page unique to their session.
I assume the only thing to do is generate the page itself as then generating an access code for each user and routing it to this page becomes quite simple.
I'm just unsure about the best way in meteor to generate this unique page each time the create is pressed.

Comment: Did you mean how to create a unique key for a session?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a unique id for the users to share. You can use routing parameters to direct them to a page, something like this

gh343hGH Is the unique id. You define your routes to pick out the unique id and the user id as variables, and then your app can get the data as required to serve up the page